# Draw moving line between points with fade out after 1 sec at one end using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw a line between points while it looks like a animated moving line with fading from end point after some time.

I can draw a moving but can't make it fade out. How can I do it? I am new to Canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('paper');
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

var startX = 50;
var startY = 50;
var endX = 1000;
var endY = 1000;
var amount = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    amount += 0.005; // change to alter duration
    if (amount > 1) amount = 1;
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.strokeStyle = "black";
    c.moveTo(startX, startY);
    // lerp : a  + (b - a) * f
    c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, startY + (endY - startY) * amount);
    c.stroke();
}, 30);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ashokd23/aucd8hgy/2/

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple way to do this is to alter the opacity of the line similarly to how you alter the amount. You can use the rgba(red, green, blue, alpha) color space the same way you would in css and just alter the alpha value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors

Example:

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById('paper');
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

var startX = 50;
var startY = 50;
var endX = 1000;
var endY = 1000;
var amount = 0;
var opacity = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    amount += 0.005; // change to alter duration
    opacity += 0.005;
    if (amount > 1) amount = 1;
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.strokeStyle = `rgba(0,0,0, ${opacity}`;
    c.moveTo(startX, startY);
    // lerp : a  + (b - a) * f
    c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, startY + (endY - startY) * amount);
    c.stroke();
}, 30);
```

```html
<canvas id="paper" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Not that this answer uses Template Literals as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals